# How to homogonize data in a Pyspark spark.sql dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I downloaded a 1.9 GB csv file containing AirBnB data. Although all the columns have a data type of "string", I have a few columns that are not "homogenous", like a column for "Amenities" where some of the entries have a count of amenities at that particular property, and others have a list of amenities. All in a string format.

So, here's what I have so far:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
SQLCtx = SQLContext(sc)

air =SQLCtx.read.load('/home/john/Downloads/airbnb-listings.csv',
                             format = "com.databricks.spark.csv",
                             header = "true",
                             sep = ";",
                             inferSchema = "true")

#check for missing values
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,sum
air.select(*(sum(col(c).isNull().cast("int")).alias(c) for c in air.columns)).show()
```

So after dropping a few columns and then removing missing values, I have this:

```
Keep = ['Price', 'Bathrooms', 'Bedrooms', 'Beds', 'Bed Type', 'Amenities',
       'Security Deposit', 'Cleaning Fee', 'Guests Included', 'Extra People',
       'Review Scores Rating', 'Cancellation Policy','Host Response Rate', 
       'Country Code', 'Zipcode']

data = air.select(*Keep)
reduced2 = data.na.drop()

#final shape after dropping missing values.
print((reduced2.count(), len(reduced2.columns)))
```

I can convert a few rows into a pandas dataframe:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(reduced2.take(50), columns = reduced2.columns)
```

A small bit of the "Amenities" list:

```
Wireless Internet,Air conditioning,Kitchen,Fre...
2                                                    10
3     Internet,Wireless Internet,Air conditioning,Ki...
4     TV,Cable TV,Internet,Wireless Internet,Air con...
5     TV,Wireless Internet,Air conditioning,Pool,Kit...
6     TV,Wireless Internet,Air conditioning,Pool,Kit...
7     Internet,Wireless Internet,Kitchen,Free parkin...
8     TV,Wireless Internet,Air conditioning,Pool,Kit...
9     Wireless Internet,Air conditioning,Kitchen,Fre...
10    TV,Cable TV,Internet,Wireless Internet,Air con...
14                                                   10
16                                                   10
17    TV,Internet,Wireless Internet,Air conditioning...
18    TV,Cable TV,Internet,Wireless Internet,Air con...
19    TV,Internet,Wireless Internet,Air conditioning...
20    TV,Wireless Internet,Air conditioning,Pool,Kit...
23    TV,Cable TV,Internet,Wireless Internet,Air con...
28                                                    9
33                                                   10
34    Internet,Wireless Internet,Kitchen,Elevator in...
37                                                   10
```

As you can see I will have trouble dealing with this as it is. 
I can do something in regular pandas easily enough to fix it, like this:

```
for i in range(len(df3['Amenities'])):
    if len(df3["Amenities"][i])>2:
        df3['Amenities'][i] = str(len(df3['Amenities'][i].split(',')))
```

Now I realize it may not be the nicest way to do it, but it turns everything that's a list into a number.
What I need is a way to do something like this to a column in a pyspark SQL dataframe, if it's at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to calculate the number of items delimited by `,`, but keep rows which are already numbers. if so, you might try the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('Amenities'
    , F.when(df.Amenities.rlike('^\d+$'), df.Amenities) \
       .otherwise(F.size(F.split('Amenities', ","))) \
       .astype("string")
).show()
```

So if the columns Amenities is an integer `df.Amenities.rlike('^\d+$')`, we will keep it as is `df.Amenities`, otherwise, use `F.size()` and `F.split()` to calculate the number of items. then convert the result to a "string"

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. One question, what does this part rlike('^\d+$') do? I have not seen that before.

Comment: @Jabernet, `rlike()` is regex match, check the document: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike. the pattern `^\d+$` means the matched value only contains 1 or more digits `[0-9]`, not any other characters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PySpark SQL Dataframes, only vanilla Pandas.

Not sure what your task is, but maybe consider turning that column in two columns. E.g. (assuming this is possible in PySpark):

```py
df['Amenities_count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amenities'], errors='coerce')
mask_entries_with_list = df['Amenities_count'].isna()
mask_entries_with_number = ~mask_entries_with_list
df.loc[mask_entries_with_number, 'Amenities'] = []
df.loc[mask_entries_with_list, 'Amenities_count'] = df['Amenities'].apply(len)
```

(untested)